# Is there any way to help avoid accidental commits to svn:externals in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I am on a development team with some members who have accidentally committed changes to svn:externals. If the externals in question are from a different repo, they get handled better in TortoiseSVN, with a clear visual separation in TortoiseSVN (see below), along with not being checked by default:

[image]

But if they're from the *same* repo (different projects in different areas of a large common repo) there is no visual indication that the files to be committed are any different.

Aside from server-side features like commit hooks, is there any way to prevent commits to externals? This is really causing some problems.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I wasn't using the latest version of TSVN. Recent versions have the [`BlockPeggedExternals` feature](https://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisesvn/tickets/285/)

Comment: The feature was available like since 2013. :)

Comment: really? Huh, I guess it's been awhile. Was it enabled by default? I installed 1.9.7.27907 in 2017 and the behavior changed when I used 1.11.0.28416. I was running 1.9.7 yesterday before I upgraded, and I was able to select pegged externals for commit... but I didn't know about the `BlockPeggedExternals` feature then.